# JMeter crashes XP when performing JDBC request

Tags: performance, automated-tests, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 2.3.2 and XP SP3. When I try a JDBC request, XP crashes. This is not very convenient.

This is the first time I've used JMeter, so I'm looking for inspiration as to where to look.

Its with a fairly simple JDBC request (simple select, without parameters, aggregated report etc).

The database is SQL server, the correct jar is in the lib directory, all of the setup is correct as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have any experience of this problem?

Comment: When you say that XP crashed, do you mean that the operating system blue screens?

Comment: No, it doesn't blue screen, but it stops responding to everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem, it was that the IP address of the URL wasn't correct.

I changed the IP address and now it works. There were lots of 'Cannot connect to IP address' in the logfile, and I think either Jmeter or XP was keeping theses connections around, until a buffer overflowed.

Its strange, but now that I know the answer, I can't reproduce the problem any more. Maybe it wasn't that after all. Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Java was running out of memory and freezing your system.